# How to resolve the export to Excel error?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an MS Access VBA code but, using it in 2016 version, getting an error.

I have tried to remove the optional part *acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12XML*

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, TableName:="Drops_Airports", FileName:=out_file, Hasfieldnames:=True, Range:="Airports"
```

The error on this code is:

> Run time error 31532-MS Access was unable to export the data

.

Comment: And what is `out_file`?

Comment: does tthe output file already exist ?

Comment: Hi Patrick, yes the output file where the table needs to be exported from Access , already exists. The procedure is actually an excel file is already available in the same directory and then the table which got created in access needs to be exported in that excel file which in code is out_file.

Comment: Out_file is a variable for an excel file where the table will get exported. Out_file = Pro_Drops.xlsx

Answer (score 1):

remove the `Range` parameter. As stated in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.transferspreadsheet):

*A string expression that's a valid range of cells or the name of a range in the spreadsheet. **This argument applies only to importing**. Leave this argument blank to import the entire spreadsheet. **When you export to a spreadsheet, you must leave this argument blank**. If you enter a range, the export will fail.*

Comment: Hi Patrick, many thanks for the response. I will remove the range and then will check and confirm back. However when this code was used a couple of days back with Ms Access 2007 version, it was working fine without any error.

Comment: Actually there are three tables which needs to be exported into three different worksheets of same workbook. hence the range is defined for three tables three different ranges.